# Changing the data type of the field value dynamically in django models

Tags: python, django, dynamic-typing

I have the follwing use case in my application:
there is a form field which is added dynamically from the backend. each variable can either be: integer, float, text, .. etc. my question is what is the best way to implemment this concept using django models or database as general.
here is my current approach:

```
class FieldValue(models.Model):
text_value = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
long_text_value = models.TextField(null=True)
date_value = models.DateField(null=True)
datetime_value = models.DateField(null=True)
number_int_value = models.IntegerField(null=True)
number_float_value = models.FloatField(null=True)
image_value = models.ImageField(null=True)
boolean_value = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class FormField(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=FIELD_TYPE_OPTIONS)
api = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
value = models.ForeignKey(FieldValue)
```

I used form-field and field-values, however, the problem here is that for any form field object I store a lot of variables although I am just using only one of them (at maximum).
Another approach can be by storing them all as strings and then doing the type checking and validation rules on the application layer but I don't think this would be efficient. any thoughts?

Comment: i think making the dynamic field a related (foreign key) model would be better.

Comment: @m0etaz Do you mean the method implemented the the sample code above?